# Ranking Function Allowing for Ties

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have a list that I need to be able to assign ranks to individual elements in, giving it a number related to its position if the list were to be sorted, allowing for ties.  For example, `{ 6, 3, 3, 6, 4, 4, 6, 4}` would be transformed to `{ 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2}` or `{ 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2}` depending on if I were sorting for higher values or lower values.

This is for a variant on PageRank, in which after assigning each point or edge a value, the set of all edges or points is ranked, with the highest ranked point(s) getting the number 1, the second highest point(s) getting 2, and so on.  I have tried using `Sort` and other approaches, but have not encountered anything that could be described as elegant.

Answer (score 12):

How about:

```
list /. Thread[# -> Ordering@#] &@Union@list
(* {3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2} *)
```

You can use the additional arguments of `Ordering` to sort it the other way:

```
list /. Thread[# -> Ordering[#, All, Greater]] &@Union@list
(* {1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2} *)
```